# Writing email reply bot using poplib and random emails keep showing up in me re.findall(...) call

Tags: python, poplib

I'm using poplib to connect to a gmail account and I want it to reply to emails that are sent to it.
However sometimes my regular expression's statement grabs random emails that aren't the one I wanted to reply to.

**For example:**

`5952f967.8543630a.1c70d.283f@mx.google.com`

**Code below:**

```
def checkEmail():

mail = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
mail.user(USER)
mail.pass_(PASS)
numEmails = len(mail.list()[1])
count = 0 

if(numEmails>=1):
    for i in range(numEmails):
        for msg in mail.retr(i+1)[1]:
            sender = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',msg)
            for s in sender:
                if s and count == 0:
                    count += 1
                    replySender(s)
                    print s
            message = email.message_from_string(msg)
count = 0
mail.quit()
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of senders that should match?

Comment: I actually figured out that I just needed to filter out the few random emails that were popping up so all is good!